# Facebook Profile Pictures for non-Friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am creating an iPhone email client that displays sender's profile pictures in in the `UITableViewCell`s in the inbox, much like Sparrow does.  I am using the following FQL query to grab these images:

```
SELECT 
    pic_big 
FROM 
    user 
WHERE 
    uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
        AND 
    strpos(lower(name),'INSERT_FIRST_THREE_LETTERS_OF_FIRST_NAME_HERE') >= 0 
        AND 
    strpos(lower(name),'INSERT_LAST_NAME_HERE') >= 0 
ORDER BY name
```

I get the names of the senders from the email headers, and then search the user's Facebook friends using the full last name and the first three letters of the first name to account for nicknames.  This works pretty well on the whole.

Sparrow, however, is able to grab profile pictures from Facebook for users I am not even friends with.  How is this possible?  I though queries were limited to specific groups, like your friends.  And that searches for email addresses were not valid?  Is this correct?  How does Sparrow grab these profile pics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user_id of any known user from their email by making an API call to:

```
 /search?type=user&q=USER@EMAIL.NET
```

If their email is registered with Facebook and public, you'll get back a JSON object with their name and user id. You'll need to make a separate call (or use a batch request) to get their picture from their ID.

Comment: This is great!  But when I plug this into a browser, I get back a facebook page with the user as the first (or only result), not a JSON object...am I approaching this the wrong way?  For example:
http://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?type=user&q=adams%20smith
returns a full page with search results instead of a JSON object.

Comment: You need to make an API call either via `https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=user&q=USER@EMAIL.NET&access_token=...` or whichever SDK you were using to make the FQL call in your original post. This endpoint requires an access token.

Comment: Ya, that makes sense.  Thanks for the hand holding haha!

Answer (score 3):

Well as long as you know the users Facebook ID - it's a long number but treat it as a string. You can use this url to get their profile picture:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture
```

No need for anything more complex.

Comment: That would be great if I could somehow get at senders' Facebook IDs, but all I have to work with is email headers.  So I would have to use a similar query to find the senders' ID, but then I would face the same problem.  Any ideas?